# Ruby Regular Expression If String has optional period, confirm only 0-2 digits follow

Tags: ruby

I want to write a regular expression with the following conditions:

- string can contain 0-1 period

  - if the string contains a period: have no more than two digits afterwards

Test conditions:

The following would *pass* the regex:

```
'foo'
'foo.'
'foo.1'
'foo.11'
''
'.'
'.1'
'.11'
'1'
'1.'
'1.1'
'1.11'
```

The following would *fail* the regex:

```
'.123'
'.1234'
'.a'
'.1a'
'.aa'
'.aaa'
```

I have been playing around with trying to get this to work on [rubular](http://rubular.com) for a bit now and am struggling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = %w(foo foo. foo.1 foo.11 . .1 .11 1 1. 1.1 1.11 .123 .1234 .a .1a .aa .aaa) + ['']
a.grep(/^\w*\.?(\d){0,2}$/m)
 => ["foo", "foo.", "foo.1", "foo.11", ".", ".1", ".11", "1", "1.", "1.1", "1.11", ""]
```

Comment: `(%w| %^.12 %^ - _  |).grep(/^\w*\.?(\d){0,2}$/m) #=> ['_']`, but the first two should both pass as there is no requirement that characters be word characters. Moreover, why should `'_'` pass but `'-'` not pass?

Answer (score 0):

```
r = /
    \A       # match beginning of string
    [^.]*  # match >= 0 characters other than a period
    \.?     # optionally match a period
    \d{,2} # match 0-2 digits
    \z       # match end of string
    /x       # free-spacing regex definition mode

(%w| foo foo. foo.1 foo.11 . .1 .11 1 1. 1.1 1.11 ^$. | << '').all? { |s| s =~ r }
  #=> true

(%w| .123 .1234 .a .1a .aa .aaa |).any? { |s| s =~ r }
  #=> false
```