# Regex to find string with optional "final" dot (and no more)

Tags: r, regex

I am getting frustrated about how to correctly add an optional "final" *full stop / period / dot* to a string in a regex. I am looking to find a string with an optional dot. If there is anything else, this should not be returned.

I tried approaches suggested in

- [Optional dot in regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26907640/optional-dot-in-regex)
- [Regex how to match an optional character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007302/regex-how-to-match-an-optional-character)
- [Ruby Regular Expression If String has optional period, confirm only 0-2 digits follow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40404758/ruby-regular-expression-if-string-has-optional-period-confirm-only-0-2-digits-f)

```r
x <- c("string", "string.", "string. and other")

grepl("string(?=\\.)", x, perl = TRUE)
#> [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
grepl("string(\\.?)", x, perl = TRUE)
#> [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
grepl("string(\\.)?", x, perl = TRUE)
#> [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
grepl("string(\\.$)?", x, perl = TRUE)
#> [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE

#desired output 
c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)
#> [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```r
grepl("^[^.]*\\.?$", x)
## => [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[^.]*` - zero or more chars other than a dot
- `\.?` - an optional dot
- `$` - end of string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lb77ei/1) and an [R demo online](https://ideone.com/FSUF5K).